# Parseval’s Identity

Tags: fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

[image]
In this proof of Parseval’s Identity, what is the justification for making the assumption $g(-t) = \overline{f(t)}$ and how does one obtain $g(t) = \overline{f(-t)}$ from $g(-t) = \overline{f(t)}$?

Comment: $g(-t)=\overline{f(t)}$ is the _definition_ of $g$ (note the word "let"). The second equation follows by  replacing $t$ by $-t$.

Comment: The author is defining $g$ since the relationship holds for all appropriate $f,g$ and their transforms.

Comment: Where did this come from, btw?  Curious because of the monumentally awful notation, using the letter $F$ for two different things in the same equation...

Comment: @David, yes I see that it is the definition. But my question is what is the justification to do so? I know this may sound strange to question a definition but I’m just wondering how to make such an assumption out of thin air? How can we be sure such an assumption can be made about $f$ and $g$ being related in this way? And this is from an Engineering Mathematics book.

Comment: @danny Maybe take a look at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Conjugation).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - this text was evidently written with a word processor with limited fonts and almost no capacity for formatting equations. It is actually better than some of the textbooks I had in college, which were written with a typewriter. They apparently decided that $F[...]$ vs $F(...)$ was sufficient to distinguish them as different symbols.

Comment: It isn't a definition. Having developed up to the "Let" for any function $g$, they are now going to apply the result to a particular function of their choosing. Since the previous formula holds for any function, it has to hold for this particular function. As for your final question, they just replaced $t$ with $-t$. Think of it in steps: let $s = -t$, then $t = -s$, so substituting for $t$ in (2), you get $$g(s) = \overline{f(-s)}$$, but $t$ and $s$ are just arbitrary variables, so now rename $s$ to $t$